# Samsung Galaxy S9+ renderscript error

Tags: android, renderscript, android-8.0-oreo

I'm working with the Camera2 API and I'm using Renderscript to perform some image processing. Everything works as expected on a range of devices(Nexus 5/5x, Pixel, Pixel 2, S8+, Note 8) except for the S9+.

Basically what I'm doing is creating an `Allocation` to receive camera data and another `Allocation` that will use the camera data, apply a transformation and the display the result on a `Surface` which will act as the camera preview. 
On the S9+ I get a black screen (no preview) and LogCat shows the following error:

[image: renderscript error]

I read the other posts regarding this type of error and they do not apply for my case because the code works as expected on other devices!

I managed to track down the error to a native library loading issue:
[image: Stacktrace]

This is only happening on the S9, the other Samsung devices work without any issues.

The S8+ is on Android Nougat(24) and the S9+ is on Oreo(26), both have OpenGL ES 3.2.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

PS: tested on other devices running Oreo without any issues

**Edit**

I updated the S9+ to the latest version (**R16NW.G965FXXU1ARCC**) but the issue still remains.
Also, based on comment suggestion, I checked the **/vendor/lib64** folder to check if the `libbccArm` and `libccc` are present, but only one of them is present:

[image]

**LATER EDIT**

`libbcc.so` found on the system but the S9+ seems to be missing the 32-bit version (S8+ on the left, S9+ on the right)

[image]

Comment: It says `libbcc.so` not found, which causes GPU to fail while initializing. 
Try restarting and resetting your device. 
Perhaps Samsung Developers failed to add this file or so which could be fixed in the next update. 
Are you working on an emulator?

Comment: @Dennis I'm using a real device, tried restarting but it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: As far as I can figure it out, it's more of a vendor issue.. you see the `libscc.so` file is located in `vendor's lib64 folder`

Comment: Try raising this issue on Samsung's FAQ page, maybe the developers can help you out.

Comment: That's a `libsccArm.so` file which you've been pointing out. Your compiler needs `libscc.so` files which still remains missing.
What are `.so` files? They're native library files, so platform specific machine code I imagine.

Comment: you are correct, `libbcc.so` is missing, not `libsccArm.so`

Comment: were you able to fix it?

Comment: No, I also posted on the samsung devs forum. But I think it's a vendor issue like you initially pointed out - it is weird however that the 64 bit version of a library will try to load a 32 bit dependency when it has the 64 bit variant...

Comment: Pl do comment on this post if you'll find a solution, I'm keen to know the results.

Comment: this is the samsung developer thread, but I don't expect much: http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=347823&messageNumber=73782&startId=zzzzz~

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Do you have any update or workaround?

Comment: @user1305336 nothing yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest update fixes renderscript issues ( I can now process 1920x1080 images).

Tested on Galaxy S9+, build number R16NW.G965FXXU1BRE5

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on the same phone.

Testing with code adapted from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/dd6c8b3/tests/RenderScriptTests/LivePreview/src/com/android/rs/livepreview/,
it looks like renderscripts are working on S9+ for lower resolutions (176x144 and 256x144 tested), but nothing above that. Probably due to restrictions of the Non-GPU renderscript driver, which is loaded as a fallback. Not much of a solution for most of us, but at least you get something on the screen.